# "negotiation timeout" when using em-ssh to connect multiple hosts in parallel

Tags: ruby, ssh, eventmachine

I use em-ssh gem (which is a net-ssh adapter for EventMachine) to execute some shell commands on multi remote hosts. Commands are executed successfully on the first host, but failed on other hosts, it complains “EventMachine::Ssh::ConnectionTerminated”
 and “EventMachine::Ssh::NegotiationTimeout”.
It seems that these hosts are competing for something maybe the port？ Can someone explains this?

```
def em_ssh_connection(ssh_host,ssh_user,ssh_password,&cb)
  EM.run do
    EM::Ssh.start("#{ssh_host}","#{ssh_user}",:password => "#{ssh_password}") do|connection|
      connection.errback do |err|
        @logger.info "#{err} (#{err.class})"
        EM.stop
      end
      connection.callback do |ssh|
        @logger.info "succcessfully connected with #{ssh_host},#{ssh_user},#{ssh_password}"
        yield ssh
        ssh.close
        EM.stop
      end
    end
  end
end 

def search_servers(ssh_host,ssh_user,ssh_password)
  em_ssh_connection(ssh_host,ssh_user,ssh_password) {|ssh|
    command = 'sed -n \'/.*server s1 [0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/=\' '+"#{@haproxy_conf}"
    myarray = em_ssh_exec(ssh,command)
    if myarray[2] == 0
      if myarray[0] != ""
        @logger.info "all tcp servers(lines): #{myarray[0]}"
        lines = myarray[0].split("\n")
        if lines.length >0
          start_line = lines[0].to_i
          stop_line = lines[lines.length-1].to_i
          @logger.info "start_line:#{start_line},stop_line:#{stop_line}"
          delete_tcp_upstream(ssh,start_line,stop_line)
        else
        end
      else
        @logger.info "the stream field in proxy file is empty"
      end
    else
      @logger.info "search all servers command failed:#{myarray[1]}"
    end
  }
end

def clear_haproxy(&cb)
   search_servers(@ssh_host1,@ssh_user1,@ssh_password1)
   search_servers(@ssh_host2,@ssh_user2,@ssh_password2)
   cb.call
end
```

Comment: You should really provide more detail to your question. What is the exact error? Can please show the code causing this error and the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: code has been attached，thx!